# DataGrip connection failed with Postgres Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I created a Docker Container as follows:

`docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=docker library/postgres`

I now want to connect it to Datagrip to query. When I try to setup a connection in Datagrip, it fails. 
[DataGrip Connection Failed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ZNv.png)
I fetched the host ip from `inspect container <container_id>`

which came out to be `172.17.0.2` on port `5432`.

Please see image for reference.
[Config Settings for the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MkUX.png) However, the connections still keeps failing when i try connecting to DataGrip.

Does anyone know how to go about it??

Comment: Are you sure the connection failure isn't due to bad credentials? Where is DatGrip running? Have you tried testing the connection from the command line using `psql`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason DataGrip failed to connect to your container running Postgres is you didn't expose any port of the container, in this case `5432`.

The IP address of the container you fetched, i.e. `172.17.0.2`, is the container's internal IP address within the docker container's network, in your case `bridge`, the default network your container connects to if you didn't specify `--network={NETWORK}` option of `docker run`.

Although there're ways to find the "real" IP address of the container, they're invariably too convoluted to be useful for you purpose. The easiest way for DataGrip to connect to your Postgres container is to **publish** your port `5432` and map it to the same port (or any other available port) of your host machine, by running:

`docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=docker -p 5432:5432 library/postgres`

with a `-p 5432:5432` option.

After that you should be able to connect to your container from DataGrip by specifying `localhost` as host. [Please see this screenshot for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ztja.png)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I battled with this for days and nothing.

If you can't connect to your `PostgreSQL` database from Datagrip via localhost and you are sure everything is as it should be,

`Windows PC`:

1. Open Services
2. Disable all PostgreSQL services running locally

Now, you can connect to `localhost:5432`

Comment: This solved it for me. You could also choose to expose PostgreSQL on another port on your local host, should you choose to keep your local PostgreSQL instance running on port 5432.